# How to integrate a .NET (C#) bitbucket project with SonarCloud to generate the sonarcloud analysis report

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, bitbucket, sonarcloud

I have a .NET project on bitbucket and what to analyze it on SonarCloud. How to integrate the .NET project with sonarcloud to get the analysis report. What are the dependencies which need to be added into the .NET (c#) project to make it visible on sonarcloud and build the analysis report.

I expect an integration of .NET C# project with sonarcloud to check the quality gate of project on sonarcloud. Steps from scratch to integrate the project with sonarcloud.

Thanks